# Sets.CartesianProduct not compatible with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, guava, cartesian-product

I need to use that function in a GWT project but the GWT version of the library doesn't include it. I tried creating my own function but it is not very performant and it is taking way too much time with big inputs. With the same input, the normal Guava library provides the result immediately.
Thanks!
Patricio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sets.cartesianProduct` **is** emulated in guava-gwt (at least in 14.0.1).

Proof: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-gwt/src-super/com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java?name=v14.0.1#877

Comment: Hello! I have downloaded the JAR file for the GWT library but the Sets class is not there, despite the documentation says something else... https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: Yes it is. The emulated version is in `com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/collect/Sets.java`, and the class itself, used for development in your IDE and to `javac` your code is in the `guava-14.0.1.jar` (you need both JARs in your classpath)

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry, I don't have much experience with Java. So I should add both JARs and then use the Sets class doing an import to com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/collect/Sets? When I add both JARs I can only import com.google.common.collect.Sets but then when I run the application I have a ClassNotFoundException... But if I follow the same steps on a normal Java application (Not GWT) it works correctly. How can I access the class under "super"?

Comment: You should add both JARs to your classpath and use `com.google.common.collect.Sets`. The file in `super` is an emulated version for GWT. If you have a ClassNotFoundException, double-check your classpath/buildpath.